# Nested SQL - equivalent of a for loop on first query

Tags: sql

I need to create a for-like kind of structure, in that I take the output of one select which is basically a list of items and for each of those items I run another sql query based on that item. I just cannot seem to find how to do this with a nested SQL. The result of the inner SQL is basically a count, so ideally the end result will be the item name and the count.

```
select distinct(item) as unique from taxonomy
select count(*) from table_name where keyword = unique
```

Ending up with:

```
item, count
car, 1,
house, 2
dog, 3
```

Comment: How familiar are you with set-theory and set-based operations? SQL doesn't use loops, it uses set-based operations. You need to adjust your thinking.

Comment: If the example you've given is representative of the problem you're trying to solve, then as Dai mentioned you wouldn't use a loop for this. As far as I can tell, you want to count rows from table_name grouped by their keyword, but only where that keyword matches an item in the table taxonomy. So you might solve this with a join like:

`SELECT tx.item, COUNT(1) FROM table_name t JOIN taxonomy tx ON t.keyword = tx.item GROUP BY tx.item`

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `select distinct` will give you distinct _rows_. Simply write `select distinct item as unique...` to make code clearer. However, you don't want select distinct here, you want a group by - as @MattSmith already said.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it with a subquery.

**Example**

```
SELECT
    t.unique AS item,
    COUNT(t2.keyword) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT item AS unique
    FROM taxonomy
) AS t
LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t.item = t2.keyword
GROUP BY t.unique;
```

Answer (score -1):

your use in SQL in this way. This is just for an example because I don't know your exact table structure, query and data. So please make changes accordingly. Hopefully, you will get understanding and able to use loop in sql

```
SELECT @parentQueryCount = COUNT(*) FROM parentQuery
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SET @RowCount = 1
WHILE(@RowCount <= @parentQueryCount)
BEGIN
    
    --for data saving
    SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM yourNestedQuery WHERE id = ___

    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1

END

-- for returning end result
SELECT * FROM #tempTable
```